# Token value is undefined trying to request API and authentication for my login page

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to get an API request from my server by using by using vue.js in Nuxt.js. I can login and logout there is not problem but the token is undefined on my console.log so maybe i made a mistake so if anyone could help me here is the code: i did not use Vuex because i want it to be just in one page.

```
export default {
  name: 'cont',
    data() {
      return {
        email: 'one@example.com',
        password: 'userone',
        error: null,
      };
  },
  methods: {
    async button() {
      const axios = require('axios').default;
      try {
        const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:33000/login', {
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password,
        });
        localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
        const status = JSON.parse(response.status);

        if(status == '200'){
          console.log(response);
          this.$router.push('/dashboard')
        }
      } catch(error){
        if(error.response){
          console.log(error.response.data);
          if(error.response.status === 400){
            this.error = true;
          } else {
            console.log(error.config)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you log the response and add it to your question?

Comment: What do you have in your devtools?